# Using a dash (-) instead of a plus (+) in Zend Framework URLs

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

by default it seems my ZF is separating multiple parameter words with plus signs.

eg. /product/test+product+name

I would like to use ->   /product/test-product-name

Here is the line from routes.ini

```
routes.product.route = "product/:productName"<br />
routes.product.defaults.controller = product<br />
routes.product.defaults.action = product
```

What can do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the URLs are urlencoded to ensure document validity. You'll need to filter/replace the terms (productName) before generating routes. A simple str_replace should be all that you need. In my app, I filter excess whitespace and then replace spaces with dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the `+` sign is commonly known to browsers to separate words, I don't thing Zend has provided an option, an most likely just uses `+`s because it is correct.

You might have to edit the source.

You may want to look at the Regex Routing [here.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) It seems like it might be useful.